# Macro for Excel to PDF Conversion

Tags: vba

I am writing below code to convert Multiple excel files in a folder to PDF but getting an error at line no. 38 which is "Invalid procedure call or argument"

I am very new to VBA so not able to catch the error,
Kindly help...

```
Sub BatchOpenMultiplePSTFiles()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objWindowsFolder As Object
    Dim strWindowsFolder As String

    'Select the specific Windows folder
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objWindowsFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a Windows folder:", 0, "")

    If Not objWindowsFolder Is Nothing Then
       strWindowsFolder = objWindowsFolder.self.Path & "\"

       Call ProcessFolders(strWindowsFolder)

       'Open the windows folder
       Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & strWindowsFolder, vbNormalFocus
   End If
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolders(strPath As String)
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objExcelFile As Object
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim strWorkbookName As String

    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFileSystem.GetFolder(strPath)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        strFileExtension = objFileSystem.GetExtensionName(objFile)
        If LCase(strFileExtension) = "xls" Or LCase(strFileExtension) = "xlsx" Then
           Set objExcelFile = objFile
           Set objWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(objExcelFile.Path)

           strWorkbookName = Left(objWorkbook.Name, (Len(objWorkbook.Name) - Len(strFileExtension)) - 1)
           objWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & strWorkbookName & ".pdf"

           objWorkbook.Close False
        End If
    Next

    'Process all folders and subfolders
    If objFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
       For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
           If ((objSubFolder.Attributes And 2) = 0) And ((objSubFolder.Attributes And 4) = 0) Then
              ProcessFolders (objSubFolder.Path)
           End If
       Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In counting lines, should I count or bypass the blank lines?  Please don't tell me line number, but rather copy the entire line and show it to me.

Comment: I tried your code and it works just fine in my case. I had bunch of pictures and 2 .xlsx files in a folder and it created 2 PDF files, as expected.

Comment: I am getting error while excuting this line:     
objWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & strWorkbookName & ".pdf"                                                                                                    In my folder I have 3 Excel files having File Type:Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
Sub Convert_Excel_To_PDF()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean
    Dim LPosition As Integer

    'Fill in the path\folder where the Excel files are
    MyPath = "C:\your_path\"

    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then


                    LPosition = InStr(1, mybook.Name, ".") - 1
                    mybookname = Left(mybook.Name, LPosition)
                    mybook.Activate
                    'All PDF Files get saved in the directory below:
                    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                        "C:\Documents and Settings\shuerya\Desktop\PDFFiles\" & mybookname & ".pdf", _
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

            End If

            mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next Fnum
    End If

    If ErrorYes = True Then
        MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
             & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: getting the same error in this line:                                    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                        "C:\Documents and Settings\shuerya\Desktop\PDFFiles\" & mybookname & ".pdf", _
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Comment: Well, for one thing, that path points to MY machine and yours is almost certainly different than mine.  Just change that you match YOUR setup, and re-run it.